# How to store retrieved data in a Hashmap?

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving map markers from Firebase successfully, but when I try to store these values in a HashMap, only the last iteration of data is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Double dLat = haoRetriever.getLat();
                Double dLong = haoRetriever.getLongitude();
                bsHaoName = haoRetriever.getName();
               Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
                       new MarkerOptions()
                               .position(new LatLng(dLat, dLong))
                               .title(bsHaoName)
                               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin)));
                mMarkers.put("MakerId", marker.getId());
                mMarkers.put("MarkerTitle", haoRetriever.getName());
                mMarkers.put("MarkerDescription", haoRetriever.getDescription());
                mMarkers.put("MarkerLocation", haoRetriever.getLocation());
            }
```

Let's say I have 5 markers being retrieved, only the details of the last marker item that is added to the HashMap.

What I want is a way to retrieve the data and store the most applicable data structure in POJO so that I will be able to iterate over them and determine what was clicked.

Comment: DataSnapshot `child` is not used anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: Yes, its currently only being used just for iteration.

Comment: How does `haoRetriever` change for each iteration?  Shouldn't you be using `child` to construct a new instance or update an instance?

Comment: Yup that is done before the code snippet above, using this line final HaoRetrieve haoRetriever = dataSnapshot.getValue(HaoRetrieve.class);

Comment: You need to post the code for `HaoRetrieve`.  It's not obvious what (if anything) causes it to advance to the data for the next child.  In the code you posted, it appears that the same data is retrieved each time.  There is nothing like "getNext()" called.

Comment: Do post the complete code snippet if possible. I can't even see where the hashmap object is.